# Code is missplacing text all over the webpage

Tags: javascript

Im really struggling with this code that i work with. I simply can't figure out what's wrong with him. I use a webuilder, and, once i insert this type of exercice( this code) the texts are going missplaced all over the webpage. :/ Screenshots wouldn't be exactly usefull as the texts are simply missplacing themselves all over the place. Any idea what could be wrong with it? My intuition told me to watch the javascript libraries, but not sure what to watch exactly.

```js
function arr(){
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("rese").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = ""
        var dropDown = document.getElementById("1");
        dropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
                var dropDown = document.getElementById("2");
        dropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
                var dropDown = document.getElementById("3");
        dropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
                        var dropDown = document.getElementById("4");
        dropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
                var dropDown = document.getElementById("5");
        dropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll('.ansimg').forEach(function(a) {
  a.remove()
})
}

function finalScore(round) {

  var correct = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll('.ansimg').forEach(function(a) {
  a.remove()
})
  var selectValue;

  var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("question");

  var numOfQuestions = questions.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) { //begin for loop

    //get the value of the select element
    selectValue = questions[i].options[questions[i].selectedIndex].value;

    //if the value equals right
    if (selectValue === "corect") { //begin if then

      //increment the correct variable
      correct = correct + 1;
        var x = document.createElement("IMG");
      x.setAttribute("src", "https://i.ibb.co/4JKs8RV/check.jpg");
      x.setAttribute("class", "ansimg");
      x.setAttribute("width", "22");
      x.setAttribute("height", "22");
      document.getElementById("img_"+i).appendChild(x);    
  
    } else if (selectValue === "gresit") { 
      var x = document.createElement("IMG");
      x.setAttribute("src", "https://i.ibb.co/XWSYMSg/wrong.jpg");
      x.setAttribute("class", "ansimg");
      x.setAttribute("width", "22");
      x.setAttribute("height", "22");
      document.getElementById("img_"+i).appendChild(x);
      correct = correct + 0;   


    } 
    else if (selectValue === "Choose")
{ 

      correct = correct + 0;

    } 

  } //end for loop

  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (round === false) {
    //get the percentage of correct answers(not rounded)
    
    document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = correct;
  } else {
  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("rese").disabled = false;
    //display the rounded value

    document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = correct;

  } //end if then else

} //end function
```

```css
  body {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #42445a;
  display: center;
  margin-bottom:flex;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

@import url
("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap");
label{ display: block; }
input[type=submit]{ margin-top: 15px; }

  #myDIV{
  display: left;
    width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:  #d8f3e5
;
  text-align: left;
     padding: 22px;
          margin-top:15px;
   margin-bottom:15px;
       border-radius:40px;
    -webkit-animation: scale-up-center 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
            animation: scale-up-center 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;    
}

/* ----------------------------------------------
 * Generated by Animista on 2020-10-23 23:50:44
 * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
 * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
 * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
 * ---------------------------------------------- */

/**
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation scale-up-center
 * ----------------------------------------
 */
@-webkit-keyframes scale-up-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
            transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes scale-up-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
            transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
#para1{
  color: darkgreen;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  
}
          #submit:disabled{
background-color: gray; /* Green */
        border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    }
        #submit:disabled:hover{
background-color: gray; /* Green */
        border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    }
    
          #rese:disabled{
background-color: gray; /* Green */
        border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    }
        #rese:disabled:hover{
background-color: gray; /* Green */
        border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    }
#aaa, #scoreDisplay, #mue{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color:green;
  font-size:17px;
  font-weight:bold;

}
input {
    background-color: darkgreen; /* Green */
        border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
   margin-top:15px;
   margin-bottom:15px;
}
input:hover  {
    background-color: green; /* Green */
        border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
      margin-top:15px;
   margin-bottom:15px;
    }
    button {
    background-color: darkgreen; /* Green */
        border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
   margin-top: 15px;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
}
button:hover  {
    background-color: green; /* Green */
        border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
      margin-top:15px;
   margin-bottom:15px;
    }
    
    select{
      margin-bottom:20px
    }
    #l1, #l2, #l3 {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      margin-top:40px;
    }
    img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#para1, #p {
  display: inline-block;
}
#img1 {
  color:darkgreen;
  font-weight:bold
}
#img2 {
  color:purple;
  font-weight:bold
}
#img3 {
  color:darkblue;
  font-weight:bold
}
```

```html
<form>


<p>

<img src="https://i.ibb.co/fMrYgG0/1a.png" alt="1a" border="0">  
<select class ="question" id="1">
<option value="Choose" selected="selected">None</option>
    <option value="gresit">Das</option>
    <option value="gresit">Die</option>
    <option value="corect">Der</option>
</select><span id="img_0"></span> &nbsp;&nbsp; Hund liebt mich! (The dog loves me!)
<br>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/G2wByxW/2.png" alt="2" border="0"> 
<select class="question" id="2">
<option value="Choose" selected="selected">None</option>
    <option value="corect">Die</option>
    <option value="gresit">Das</option>
    <option value="gresit">Der</option>
</select><span id="img_1"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;  Katze ist flauschig! (The kitty is fluffy!)
<br>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/5rGssWm/3.png" alt="3" border="0"> 
<select class="question" id="3">
<option value="Choose" selected="selected">None</option>
    <option value="gresit">Die</option>
    <option value="gresit">Der</option>
    <option value="corect">Das</option>
</select><span id="img_2"></span>  &nbsp;&nbsp; haus ist klein! (The house is small!)
<br>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/Z1wRjvy/4.png" alt="4" border="0"> 
<select class="question" id="4">
<option value="Choose" selected="selected">None</option>
    <option value="gresit">Der</option>
    <option value="corect">Die</option>
    <option value="gresit">Das</option>
</select><span id="img_3"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Frau ist schlau! (The woman is smart!)
<br>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/pvtQ7tx/5.png" alt="5" border="0"> 
<select class="question" id="5">
<option value="Choose" selected="selected">None</option>
    <option value="gresit">Die</option>
    <option value="corect">Der</option>
    <option value="gresit">Das</option>
</select><span id="img_4"></span>  &nbsp;&nbsp;  Mann ist stark!
<br>




<button type="button" id ="submit" onclick="finalScore(true)">Check</button>       
<button type="button" id="rese" disabled onclick="arr()" >Try again</button>
<div  id="myDIV" style=display:none  ><div id="para1">Here's your feedback!
    </div><img src="https://i.ibb.co/1K8hCvB/gr5.png" alt="!" width="70" height="70" id="p"><br><br>
 <p id= "aaa">Your score is:  </p><p id="scoreDisplay"></p> <p id=mue>/ 5 </p>
 
 <div class ="lol">According to Mr. Puddle, we use  <span id= "img1">Der </span> for masculine,  <span id= "img2">die </span> for feminine and <span id= "img3">Das</span>  for neuter gender. It may look a bit conffusing in the beggining, we know! But practice makes it better so keep going!<br>

 

 </div></div>
 </p></form>
```

Comment: You mean, when you put the cross or tick, the text moves?

Comment: try adding `.ansimg {
position:absolute;
}` to the style

Comment: also, `[ &nbsp;&nbsp; ]` vs `[&nbsp;&nbsp; ]` missing space in one line

Comment: that's a lot of code. can you isolate one or 2 lines of code that are causing the problem?

Comment: I'd also add `span[id^="img_"] {
margin:0 5px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You inconsistently used

```
> &nbsp;&nbsp; text
>&nbsp;&nbsp; text
```

So there's an alignment issue there

Once the check/cross images are put in everything shifts - so that doesn't look nice either

Simply removing those `&nbsp;` and using padding for the `<span id=img_#>` and setting the `.ansimg` to `position:absolute` - now everything lines up, and doesn't shift

So, the following, removes the `&nbsp;` and adds two styles

```
.ansimg {
  position: absolute;
}

span[id^="img_"] {
  padding-right: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 0.4em;
}
```

```js
function arr() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("rese").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = ""
  var dropDown = document.getElementById("1");
  dropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
  var dropDown = document.getElementById("2");
  dropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
  var dropDown = document.getElementById("3");
  dropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
  var dropDown = document.getElementById("4");
  dropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
  var dropDown = document.getElementById("5");
  dropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll('.ansimg').forEach(function(a) {
    a.remove()
  })
}

function finalScore(round) {

  var correct = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll('.ansimg').forEach(function(a) {
    a.remove()
  })
  var selectValue;

  var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("question");

  var numOfQuestions = questions.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) { //begin for loop

    //get the value of the select element
    selectValue = questions[i].options[questions[i].selectedIndex].value;

    //if the value equals right
    if (selectValue === "corect") { //begin if then

      //increment the correct variable
      correct = correct + 1;
      var x = document.createElement("IMG");
      x.setAttribute("src", "https://i.ibb.co/4JKs8RV/check.jpg");
      x.setAttribute("class", "ansimg");
      x.setAttribute("width", "22");
      x.setAttribute("height", "22");
      document.getElementById("img_" + i).appendChild(x);

    } else if (selectValue === "gresit") {
      var x = document.createElement("IMG");
      x.setAttribute("src", "https://i.ibb.co/XWSYMSg/wrong.jpg");
      x.setAttribute("class", "ansimg");
      x.setAttribute("width", "22");
      x.setAttribute("height", "22");
      document.getElementById("img_" + i).appendChild(x);
      correct = correct + 0;


    } else if (selectValue === "Choose") {

      correct = correct + 0;

    }

  } //end for loop

  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (round === false) {
    //get the percentage of correct answers(not rounded)

    document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = correct;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("rese").disabled = false;
    //display the rounded value

    document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = correct;

  } //end if then else

} //end function
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #42445a;
  display: center;
  margin-bottom: flex;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

@import url ("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap");
label {
  display: block;
}

input[type=submit] {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#myDIV {
  display: left;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #d8f3e5;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 22px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  -webkit-animation: scale-up-center 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
  animation: scale-up-center 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
}


/* ----------------------------------------------
 * Generated by Animista on 2020-10-23 23:50:44
 * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
 * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
 * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
 * ---------------------------------------------- */


/**
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation scale-up-center
 * ----------------------------------------
 */

@-webkit-keyframes scale-up-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes scale-up-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

#para1 {
  color: darkgreen;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#submit:disabled {
  background-color: gray;
  /* Green */
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#submit:disabled:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  /* Green */
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#rese:disabled {
  background-color: gray;
  /* Green */
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#rese:disabled:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  /* Green */
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#aaa,
#scoreDisplay,
#mue {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: green;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  /* Green */
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

input:hover {
  background-color: green;
  /* Green */
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

button {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  /* Green */
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: green;
  /* Green */
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

select {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

#l1,
#l2,
#l3 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#para1,
#p {
  display: inline-block;
}

#img1 {
  color: darkgreen;
  font-weight: bold
}

#img2 {
  color: purple;
  font-weight: bold
}

#img3 {
  color: darkblue;
  font-weight: bold
}


/* added this */

.ansimg {
  position: absolute;
}

span[id^="img_"] {
  padding-right: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 0.4em;
}
```

```html
<form>


  <p>

    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/fMrYgG0/1a.png" alt="1a" border="0">
    <select class="question" id="1">
      <option value="Choose" selected="selected">None</option>
      <option value="gresit">Das</option>
      <option value="gresit">Die</option>
      <option value="corect">Der</option>
    </select><span id="img_0"></span>Hund liebt mich! (The dog loves me!)
    <br>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/G2wByxW/2.png" alt="2" border="0">
    <select class="question" id="2">
      <option value="Choose" selected="selected">None</option>
      <option value="corect">Die</option>
      <option value="gresit">Das</option>
      <option value="gresit">Der</option>
    </select><span id="img_1"></span>Katze ist flauschig! (The kitty is fluffy!)
    <br>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5rGssWm/3.png" alt="3" border="0">
    <select class="question" id="3">
      <option value="Choose" selected="selected">None</option>
      <option value="gresit">Die</option>
      <option value="gresit">Der</option>
      <option value="corect">Das</option>
    </select><span id="img_2"></span>haus ist klein! (The house is small!)
    <br>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Z1wRjvy/4.png" alt="4" border="0">
    <select class="question" id="4">
      <option value="Choose" selected="selected">None</option>
      <option value="gresit">Der</option>
      <option value="corect">Die</option>
      <option value="gresit">Das</option>
    </select><span id="img_3"></span>Frau ist schlau! (The woman is smart!)
    <br>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/pvtQ7tx/5.png" alt="5" border="0">
    <select class="question" id="5">
      <option value="Choose" selected="selected">None</option>
      <option value="gresit">Die</option>
      <option value="corect">Der</option>
      <option value="gresit">Das</option>
    </select><span id="img_4"></span>Mann ist stark!
    <br>




    <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="finalScore(true)">Check</button>
    <button type="button" id="rese" disabled onclick="arr()">Try again</button>
    <div id="myDIV" style=display:none>
      <div id="para1">Here's your feedback!
      </div><img src="https://i.ibb.co/1K8hCvB/gr5.png" alt="!" width="70" height="70" id="p"><br><br>
      <p id="aaa">Your score is: </p>
      <p id="scoreDisplay"></p>
      <p id=mue>/ 5 </p>

      <div class="lol">According to Mr. Puddle, we use <span id="img1">Der </span> for masculine, <span id="img2">die </span> for feminine and <span id="img3">Das</span> for neuter gender. It may look a bit conffusing in the beggining, we know! But practice makes it better
        so keep going!<br>



      </div>
    </div>
  </p>
</form>
```